# freeing memory allocated by cudamallocpitch

Tags: memory, cuda

How do we free memory allocated by     cudaMallocPitch. I tried to find in programming guide, but could not get the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cudaFree()` just like most other CUDA `malloc()s`. See docs:

"Frees the memory space pointed to by devPtr, which must have been returned by a previous call to cudaMalloc() or cudaMallocPitch()."

http://tinyurl.com/8y3hj35

Comment: A related question: can cudaMemcpy also be used for memory allocated with cudaMallocPitch?